# C - Putting all the wav file paths from a folder and subfolder into an array of string with a recursive function

Tags: c, file, recursion, directory, subdirectory

I'm having some trouble with the code below it sould take the path to a folder as input (in my case "pack") and put the paths to each .wav file it can find in the folder or in subfolders into an array of string.

The code you can see below crashes.

Before asking you guys some help I've search by myself and the crash seems to append while in the second subfolder when trying to realloc for the first file of that folder

The folder structure I'm testing with goes like this :

```
pack
├── _subfolder1
|   ├── wavefile1.wav
|   ├── wavefile2.wav
|   └── wavefile3.wav
├── _subfolder2
|   └── wavefile4.wav
├── _subfolder3
|   ├── wavefile5.wav
|   └── wavefile6.wav
```

code :

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void find_dir_content(char* path, char** filepathlist, int* size)
{

    DIR* d = opendir(path);
    if(d == NULL)
        return;
    struct dirent* dir;

    while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) 
    {
        int isdir = 0;
        DIR* tmp;
        char f_path[255]; 
        sprintf(f_path, "%s/%s", path, dir->d_name);
        if((tmp = opendir(f_path))) { 
            closedir(tmp);
            isdir = 1;
        }

        if(!isdir) {

            char *dot = strrchr(dir->d_name, '.');
            if (dot && !strcmp(dot, ".wav")){
                char** tmp = realloc(filepathlist, sizeof(char*) * ((*size)  + 1));
                if (tmp == NULL)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    filepathlist = tmp;
                }
                char d_path[256];
                sprintf(d_path, "%s/%s", path, dir->d_name);
                filepathlist[*size] = d_path;
                //printf("%d : %s\n", *size, filepathlist[*size]);
                (*size)++;

            }
        }
        else if(isdir && strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 &&
            strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            char d_path[256];
            sprintf(d_path, "%s/%s", path, dir->d_name);
            //printf("%s\n", d_path);
            find_dir_content(d_path, filepathlist, size);


        }
    }
    closedir(d);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int sizefilepathlist = 0;
    char** filepathlist = (char**) malloc(0*sizeof(char*));
    find_dir_content("pack", filepathlist, &sizefilepathlist);
    for(int i = 0; i< sizefilepathlist; i++){
        printf("%s", filepathlist[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I'm on windows, I use codelite with minGW(gcc), and there is no error message, windows just gives me the old "has stopped working" error.

Comment: Please also provide the error messages and some details on versions and platform!

Comment: You're storing the address of a local variable. That will get you undefined behavior. You must dynamically allocate room for the path itself, not just the pointer to it. If you have `strdup()` use that, else re-implement it.

Comment: BTW, unless it's your homework, you can opt in "file tree walk" - https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw, or even use high-level languages/libraries

Comment: `sprintf` is dangerous, use `snprintf` at the very least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @unwind in the comments:

> You're storing the address of a local variable. That will get you undefined behavior. You must dynamically allocate room for the path itself, not just the pointer to it.

The smallest change would be to change the line:

```
            filepathlist[*size] = d_path;
```

to

```
            filepathlist[*size] = strdup(d_path); // d_path will go out of scope - copy the string to dynamically allocated memory.
```

Make sure you `#include <string.h>` to get the prototype for `strdup`.

**EDIT:**

Another problem is that when you `realloc(filepathlist)` the variable in `main` still points to the old location. This can be fixed by letting `find_dir_content` return the current location of `filepathlist`:

```
char **filepathlist(...) {
    ...
    return filepathlist;
}
```

and in main:

```
filepathlist = find_dir_content("pack", filepathlist, &sizefilepathlist);
```

Comment: Thank you and @unwind for your answers, I'm sure they have fixed a part of the problem but the error is still here

Comment: @halcaponey I've added another bugfix